# Erro em anotação da lib Parceler

Tags: android

Estou implementando uma classe que implementa `Parcelable` e estou utilizando a lib `Parceler`, mas quando vou rodar o aplicativo aparece o seguinte erro:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - parceler-1.0.3.jar (org.parceler:parceler:1.0.3)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.

Como o erro está mostrando é um problema na anotação que fiz na classe, mas não consigo entender o que está errado.

```
 @org.parceler.Parcel

public class Carro
{
   //Atributos da classe
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 6601006766832473959L;
   public long id;
   public String tipo;
   public String nome;
   public String desc;
   public String urlFoto;
   public String urlInfo;
   public String urlVideo;
   public String urlLatitude;
   public String urlLongitude;

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Carro{" + "nome-'" + nome + "/" + "}";
   }
```

}

E no `build.gradle` :

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler:1.0.3'
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.3'
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o [Github do Parceler](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler), para usar o Parceler você tem de usar essas 2 linhas no gradle:

```
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'
```